# Strange behaviour of string length function w.r.t null character?

Tags: c++, string

I have this code say:

```
 std::string str("ashish");  
 str.append("\0\0");  
 printf("%d", str.length());
```

It is printing 6 but if I have this code

```
 std::string str("ashish");  
 str.append("\0\0",2);  
 printf("%d", str.length());
```

it is printing 8 ! Why?

Comment: thanks @luchian I put 4 space, dont know why it didnt work

Comment: there was no space between the text and the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `str.append("\0\0")` uses the null character to determine the end of the string. So "\0\0" is length zero. The other overload, `str.append("\0\0",2)`, just takes the length you give it, so it appends two characters.

From the standard:

> ```
>   basic_string&
>    append(const charT* s, size_type n);
> ```
>
> 7         *Requires:* `s` points to an array of at least `n` elements of `charT`.
>
> 8         *Throws:* length_error if size() + n > max_size().
>
> 9         *Effects:* The function replaces the string controlled by `*this` with a string of length `size() + n` whose first `size()` elements are a copy of the original string controlled by `*this` and whose remaining elements are a copy of the initial `n` elements of `s`.
>
> 10         *Returns:* `*this`.
>
> ```
>   basic_string& append(const charT* s);
> ```
>
> 11         *Requires:* `s` points to an array of at least `traits::length(s) + 1` elements of `charT`.
>
> 12         *Effects:* Calls `append(s, traits::length(s))`.
>
> 13         *Returns:* `*this`.
>
> *— [string::append] 21.4.6.2 p7-13*

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> `string& append ( const char * s, size_t n );`
>
> Appends a copy of the
>   string formed by the first n characters in the array of characters
>   pointed by s.
>
> `string& append ( const char * s );`
>
> Appends a copy of the
>   string formed by the null-terminated character sequence (C string)
>   pointed by s. The length of this character sequence is determined by
>   the first ocurrence of a null character (as determined by
>   traits.length(s)).

The second version (your first one) takes into account the null-terminator (which in your case is exactly the first character). The first one doesn't.