# Is length of std::string consistent despite string having null terminated characters?

Tags: c++11

My question arises from reading a comment of function length() and size() in basic_string.h of libstdc++, that is distributed with Ubuntu 14.04:

The comment states the following:

*Returns the number of characters in the string, not including any null-termination.*

This comment to me is confusion in the case where strings only contains null terminating characters, especially when considering how strlen works traditionally, and I am concerned that compilers might implement strings in a way where they don't return the size() but the length as determined by char_traits::length().

Whilst it might obvious that a string length is known without requiring null terminating characters, the notion of the length of a traditional string is not the same as that of a container. I feared that this might have changed at some point, and I'm wondering at the risk of code like the code below ...

```
std::string header(4, char{});
assert(header.length() == 4);
```

... not being entirely cross platform.

I'm assuming it (the question) must hold valid, and my assumption is from this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size):

Comment: Yes, it holds as per the standard.

Comment: Probably a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285060/strange-behaviour-of-string-length-function-w-r-t-null-character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where strings only contains null terminating characters

Those are not "null terminated characters", since they don't *terminate* the string, they are part of it. They are null characters, but not null terminated.

The behaviour you see is guaranteed by the standard. You told the `string` to create a string of four null characters, so that's what you get.

That would be a ridiculous thing to be non-portable between compilers, or between revisions of the standard. It's always been guaranteed.

> My question also arises because this is inconsistent with the traditional behavior of strlen, and char_traits::length()

That's irrelevant, because a `char*` doesn't know its length. A `std::string` does.

I'll change the comment in the libstdc++ header that confused you to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't consider it entirely irrelevant, although admittedly I've not read the precise detail of e.g older standards (e.g c++98). I could imagine that older standards or compilers may have done so for consistency sake. It's not hard to image (perhaps erroneously) that length would be used in the traditional sense (up to null terminator), and size() in the container sense.
BTW, with respect - why downmark me?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research. CHanging the meaning of `std::string::length()` between standard revisions would also be pretty silly.

Comment: I have looked at the existing standard. My question relates to the risk involved with historical considerations. Actually, my question arises from looking at glibcpp source code,and seeing that the code does not do what the comment states..., the comment mentioning null termination, which is irrelevant. I've done research...

Comment: Standards and lib comments don't match up, and  I want to know which to believe, and where/when the discrepancy came

Comment: What is glibcpp? What comment are you talking about? What discrepancy? You do realise cppreference.com is not the standard, right? But if the behaviour was different between standards then cppreference.com would mention it.

Comment: Also, if your question is really about a discrepancy between a comment in a header and the standard, why didn't you mention anything about that in the question?

Comment: The cpp library that is shipped with gcc on my pc. Yes, I do realise this,but I also realise it's a good reference and more reader friendly in my opinion.

Comment: **Which comment?** I don't know which line of which libstdc++ header on your PC you are looking at!

Comment: Without mentioning a specific library, I wanted to know whether the discrepancy may have existed,and whether the code was risky. Enough said. I'll remove the question at some point.

Comment: Do you mean _"Returns the number of characters in the string, not including any null-termination."_? That's not a discrepancy, the comment is correct. It refers to the null terminator after the end of the string (which is guaranteed to be there, see [c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)). Embedded nulls _inside_ the string do not terminate it.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to that comment, which is likened to strlen, and which causes confusion when the string contains "only" null characters. IMO this DOES cause confusion, especially when considering strings tradisionally

Comment: I've edited my answer to say that embedded zeros are not "null terminated characters" or "null termination". A "terminator" character must come at the end, by definition, but zeros in a `std::string` are not terminators.

Comment: I've modified my question. Let me know if this is more suitable please

Comment: OK, downvote removed, but my answer still already answers that question. You say: _"where strings only contains null terminating characters"_ but you are confusing "null characters" with "null terminating characters". A std::string can contain null characters, but they do not terminate it.